# For loop in BASH to get username and password tuple

Tags: bash, dictionary-attack

I am writing a simple script with Bash 4.4.23, to perform a demonstrative *dictionary attack* towards various web servers which use default passwords.

The arrays containing usernames and passwords are declared above the "for" cycles, which are as follows:

```
for i in $usernames
do for j in $passwords
    do printf '%s ' "${usernames[*]}:${passwords[*]}"
done
done
```

The code should return something like:

```
root:root root:admin admin:admin admin:root
```

But instead it is returning

```
root admin:root admin
```

Which are the values declared within the arrays (*usernames* and *passwords*).

How can I achieve what I'm trying to do? The tuples will then have to be passed to curl in order to perform the dictionary attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the arrays and the elements you loop over mixed up. You loop over the array. You use the loop variable inside the loop.

```
for i in "${usernames[@]}"
  do for j in "${passwords[@]}"
    do printf '%s:%s ' "$i" "$j"
  done
done
```

The symptom you see is because `$usernames` alone refers to the first element of the array, and similarly for the other array variable.

Answer (score 0):

wildcard wont work here. Try

```
for i in $usernames
do for j in $passwords
    do printf '%s:%s ' "$i:$j"
done
done
```

Comment: There is no wildcard here. `${usernames[*]}` is how you refer to the entire array (though `"${usernames[@]}"` is somewhat more correct, just like you should prefer `"$@"` over `$*`).